# How to remove this error: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 public function addAppdetails()
    {   $dev_id = $this->sessionStart();

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('appname', 'App Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('platform', 'Platform', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('category','App Category','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'App Description', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('app_pic','App Pic','required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('file','App File','required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $appname = $this->input->post('appname');
            $platform = $this->input->post('platform');
            $category1 = $this->input->post('category');
            $descripton = $this->input->post('description');
            $category = implode(",", $category1);
            echo "l";
            $data1=$this->appFileupload();
            echo "Break";
            $data2=$this->appImageupload();
            die;
            foreach ($data1 as $dataArray)
            {
                $fileName=$dataArray['file_name'];
            }
            foreach ($data2 as $dataArray)
            {
                $imageName=$dataArray['file_name'];
            }

            $data = array('name' => $appname, 'platform' => $platform, 'description' => $descripton, 'category' => $category,'file_name'=>$fileName,'image_name'=>$imageName,'dev_id'=>$dev_id);
                $this->Dev_model->addApp($data);

            //$this->appImageupload();
            echo "yolo";



        }
        else
        {
            $data['dataArray'] = $this->sessionStart();
            $category = $this->input->post('category');
            print_r($category);
            $this->load->view('dev/addApp', $data);
        }
    }

public function appFileupload()
{
    $config1['upload_path']          = './uploads/files';
    $config1['allowed_types']        = 'apk|exe';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config1);

    if ( ! $this->upload->appFileUpload('file'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);

    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        return $data;

    }
}

public function appImageupload()
{
    $config2['upload_path']          = './uploads/appImages';
    $config2['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config2['max_size']             = 1000000000;
    $config2['max_width']            = 10240000;
    $config2['max_height']           = 76800000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config2);

    if ( ! $this->upload->appImageUpload('app_pic'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);

    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;

    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
lBreak
Array ( [error] =>
    The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
)
```

So, if I exchange the positions of `appFileupload()` and `appImageupload()` then it will give the same error for 'apk|exe' file and right now it is giving the error for `appImageupload()`. If you will ask how do I know about this? Then the answer is, I have checked their folder one gets uploaded but not the other.

#### CodeIgniter version is: 3.x

Comment: This approach is wrong `$data1=$this->appFileupload(); $data2=$this->appImageupload();`. Ex if you upload image it will go to file upload and then goes to image upload. If this is two methods separate it to two. If this is the same method then allow all in one. without adding the same function twice

Comment: They're already separated sir. The image function will upload images while file upload will upload an APK or exe file. How can I separate them according to you? Thanks for the answer thought :)

Comment: this upload has two forms or one form ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam one form

Answer (score 0):

Add * in place of another type.

```
 $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

I am just suggesting this for test purpose

#### Edit:

I am not sure but this will be helpful.

You could try looking at system/libraries/Upload.php line 199:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
```

Change that line to:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();
```

Comment: I know it will work but this is not the solution I'm looking for because it will allow to upload all file type which I don't want

Comment: @VyomSrivastava are you have updated the Codeigniter to 2.0 to 3.0 recently ?

Comment: Try to change the system upload library. Copy paste the old upload library file. I have experienced a little similar problem so this is what I do. May it help. @VyomSrivastava

Answer (score 0):

Well Lol, I'm answering my own question.

First, loading the library again with $config2 won't work because the library is already loaded once and $config1 will stay loaded. To load a new config use:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config2);
```